# Unable to decode toml file

Tags: go, toml

I want to read configs from a toml file.

conf/conf.toml

```
db_host = "127.0.0.1"

db_port = 3306

db_user = "root"

db_password ="123456"
```

conf/conf.go file

```
package conf

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
)

type appcfg struct {
    DbHost     string `toml:"db_host"`
    DbPort     string `toml:"db_port"`
    DbUser     string `toml:"db_user"`
    DbPassword string `toml:"db_password"`
}

var (
    App       *appcfg
    defConfig = "./conf/conf.toml"
)

func init() {

    var err error
    App, err = initCfg()
    log.Println(App.DbHost)

}

func initCfg() (*appcfg, error) {
    app := &appcfg{}
    _, err := toml.DecodeFile(defConfig, &app)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return app, nil
}
```

When I run this program, I get an error that I don't know how to fix:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: why do you edit your typos back? I had fixed your spelling and formatting.

Comment: sorry ,i did't see your edit  thanks

Comment: thanks @blackgreen ,the conf is a module，i import in main.go

Comment: @yuyu1630 doesn't matter what you import and whether xyz is a module or not. You need to check the error returned by initCfg as already pointed out by blackgreen. The error will tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Reposting [Comin2021](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17259898/comin2021)'s now deleted answer in English, since it was accepted by the OP)

You defined the type of your `DbPort` as `string` but it appears as an integer in your configuration file. Change it as below:

```
type appcfg struct {
    DbHost     string `toml:"db_host"`
    DbPort     int64  `toml:"db_port"`  // change this
    DbUser     string `toml:"db_user"`
    DbPassword string `toml:"db_password"`
}
```

Also check that `initCfg` second return value `err` is not empty and log it.